# Numbering a figure with a symbol in a way that is compatible with \label and \ref

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, symbols, cross-referencing, captions

In a long paper, full of figures labeled as usual, there are two figures which I would like to single out and label with symbols.  For instance, I would like to have them labeled `Figure $\dag$` and `Figure $\ddag$`.  I would like to do this in a way that is compatible with `\label` and `\ref`, so that when I refer to `Figure $\dag$` `\label{dagfig`} with `\ref{dagfig}`, I get `$\dag$`.  I would also like the figures to appear with this labeling in the list of figures.  Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can redefine `\thefigure` locally and step down the `figure` counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\renewcommand\thefigure{$\dag$}
\caption{Figure dag}
\label{fig:dag}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\renewcommand\thefigure{$\ddag$}
\caption{Figure ddag}
\label{fig:ddag}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\end{figure}

Figures~\ref{fig:dag}, and~\ref{fig:ddag}...

\begin{figure}
\caption{Regular figure}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**egreg** has suggested a refinement to the above solution using a new command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\specialcaption[1]{%
  \@namedef{the\@captype}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{\@captype}{-1}\caption}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\specialcaption{$\dag$}{Figure dag}
\label{fig:dag}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\specialcaption{$\ddag$}{Figure ddag}
\label{fig:ddag}
\end{figure}

Figures~\ref{fig:dag}, and~\ref{fig:ddag}...

\begin{figure}
\caption{Regular figure}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`\specialcaption` also admits the optional argument, as in

```
\specialcaption{$\dag$}[short]{long}
```

and, since it uses `\@captype`, this command can also be used in the `table` environment. Usual precautions about using fragile commands also apply to `\specialcaption`.

Comment: Gonzalo, look in the chat.